# Variation problem with min and max (ball in bags, different colors)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Suppose there are $N\in\mathbb N$ balls in a bag and that $n_1,n_2,n_3 \in\mathbb N$ of them are colored red, green and blue respectively (so $n_1+n_2+n_3=N$). What is the number of ways of choosing $r\leq N$ balls from the bag.

I suspect that the number is a formula having $\min$ and $\max$ (because $r$ need not depend individually on the $n_i$). I was able to solve these kind of problem if I have small numbers (by counting using brute force) but I would really prefer a formula for this. I would also like to extend this problem if we have say $k$ colors instead of just $3$.

Answer (score 0):

For given values of $N$ and $r$ and assuming you are choosing without replacement, you will first have to solve the diophantine equation
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3=r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)
$$
Then, you will have to perform the summation 
$$
\sum_{x_1+x_2+x_3=r}\binom{n_1}{x_1}\binom{n_2}{x_2}\binom{n_3}{x_3}
$$
on all integer solutions of $(1)$, satisfying $x_i\leq n_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: The problem is the same as solving the diophantine equation with the additional inequality restriction $x_i\leq n_i$. But the summation you propose is not practical because I need to individually count these $x_i$, it seems to be no different than brute force. Btw. I note, if $x_i>n_i$ then you are setting the choose to be $0$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that, say, the red balls are distinguishable, but that the order of selection is not

Comment: I agree with Henry. That is not the problem

Comment: $Henry: I am assuming the usual conventions of choices without replacement. So, yes, I assume that balls of the same color are distinguishable (in the sense that the choices are made without replacement and so a bigger number of balls gives more possible choices from this color) and the order of choice is not taken into account.

Comment: @quantum, would you mind giving some more hints (maybe by editing the post) on what are your exact assumptions for the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if adding more words will make this clearer. I think it is better to illustrate by an example. Suppose there are 0 blue balls (I said they are in $\mathbb N$ but this example still is ok), 2 green balls, 2 red balls. You have only 2 ways of choosing 3 balls (2 green 1 red , or 1 green 2 red). Your formula suggests ${2\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{0\choose 0}+{2\choose 2}{2\choose 1}{0\choose 0}=4$

Comment: @quantum, I feel that the statement of the problem is not clear. You are not specifying what you have in mind by the term "choosing". In your example (which should better be included in your post rather than posted as a comment), if you take into account that balls of the same color are distinguishable, then you have $4$ choices: 2 green and either of the two red (these are two) , or either of the two green and the 2 red balls (these are the other two. This is the meaning of my formula.

Comment: On the other hand, if you assume the balls (of the same color) to be indistinguishable, then in any case, the number of choices is simply equal to the number of solutions of the diophantine equation (see my post) satisfying $x_i\leq n_i$, $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: @Konkan for your last comment yes (except for the formula). For the previous comment, I thought the color in the problem automatically implies that I assume them to be indistinguishable. I think this is a common understanding (as, I believe, Henry also realized). I'll see how the other people react to this problem and if this is indeed unclear to most then I will add this.

Comment: @quantum: regarding the indistinguishable thing, let us think of the follwing situation: Imagine we have $1000$ balls: $1$ red and $999$ blue. Then, if we take into account your understanding of indistinguishable, there is only one way of choosing $2$ balls of  different color. Do you find this reasonable? My point is that if we adopt such an interpretation of the question, then the values of $n_i$ and $N$ itself, become of little or no importance. (they are just restrictions to the values of $r$ and $x_i$).